# How to properly manage manifest before releasing android APP?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-manifest

Can someone help me i am new on android and i have published my app but its been 6 days i get no download from anyone. I think the issue with my manifest file. Do i need to add someone in manifest to get index by google playstore here is my manifest example`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.blogspot.znetworktv.facebookupdate"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".why" />
        <activity android:name=".Kion" />
        <activity android:name=".Past" />
        <activity android:name=".war" />
        <activity android:name=".Start" />
        <activity android:name=".bestad" />
        <activity android:name=".start2"></activity>`
```

Comment: Wait, as far as I can tell, you didn't actually publish your app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.znetworktv.facebookupdate I can't see it on Play Store

Comment: thank you for answering i have asked the question again can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258056/i-am-new-on-android-i-published-my-app-but-its-been-12-days-i-get-no-download-i?noredirect=1#comment83498604_48258056

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to add anything to manifest.

The problem is more likely in the title, screenshots and description of your app in Play Store. Check out [Get discovered on Google Play search](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/4448378?hl=en) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for replying but can i ask one more questions
there are many lame app's in playstore getting lots and lots of download did you checked my manifest file is everything fine with it if yes than what is the purpose of this intent in the manifest which i mentioned down below ?
--
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> </intent-filter>

Comment: @FastReviewRobo yes, everything is fine. Check documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html